# Сортировка DataGridTextColumn с коллекцией DataView и сложным типом колонки

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть `DataTable` одна из колонок имеет объекты типа `B` и имя её `Exemplar`

```
class A { public string SubProperty { get; set; } }
class B { public A Property { get; set; } }
```

также имеется разметка `xaml`

```
<DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" HeadersVisibility="Column" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Name="f_Test">
  <DataGrid.Columns>
    <DataGridTextColumn Header="Test" Binding="{Binding Path=Exemplar.Property.SubProperty}"/>
  </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Все отображает корректно, однако при попытке сортировки этой колонки возникает исключение

> Тип "" не имеет свойства с именем "Exemplar.Property.SubProperty", поэтому сортировка данных невозможна

Ниже код заполнения таблицы и привязка к `DataGrid`

```
  DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
  tbl.Columns.Add("Exemplar", typeof(B));
  DataRow row = tbl.NewRow();
  row["Exemplar"] = new B() { Property = new A() { SubProperty = "Sub1" } };
  tbl.Rows.Add(row);
  f_Test.ItemsSource = tbl.DefaultView;
```

UPD: Или мне проще в `ItemsSource` запихать `Dictionary` и не париться?

Comment: Почему вы используете `DataTable`, а не нормальную коллекцию?

Comment: Попробуйте указать у колонки указать `SortMemberPath`. Например: <DataGridTextColumn SortMemberPath="MyPropertу" />

Comment: @Андрей я тоже к этому склоняюсь... думаю ну к черту этот DataTable

Comment: @sp7 SortMemberPath="Exemplar.Property.SubPropertу" вызывает то же исключение

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик со стандартной `ObservableCollection<T>` сортировка работает как надо. С `DataTable` не проверял )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как вариант, могу предложить - избавится от `DataTable`, как уже и говорили и использовать `ObservableCollection<T>`, либо, если очень хочется, то можно убрать комплексный тип у колонки

`tbl.Columns.Add("Exemplar", typeof(B));`

и использовать только простые типы, например:

```
DataTable tbl = new DataTable();
tbl.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
tbl.Columns.Add("Age", typeof(int));
```

в этом случае, сортировка работает как надо.

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Возраст" Binding="{Binding Age}" CanUserSort="True" SortMemberPath="Name" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Имя" Binding="{Binding  Name}" CanUserSort="False" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Comment: Да, так и сделал, просто интересовал вопрос почему DataTable по биндингу значение выдает, а сортировать отказывается.

Comment: это все-таки не ответ на поставленный вопрос.